# Nonequal Sets with the Same Inf and Sup

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose two sets A and B are nonempty, such that sup(A)=sup(B) and inf(A)=inf(B). Does this mean that A=B? I am thinking no, with a simple counterexample. Suppose set A is $A=\{x|0\leq x \leq 1\}$ and $B=\{x|0<x<1\}.$ Then these two sets would have sup(A)=sup(B) and inf(A)=inf(B) but $A\neq B$. Is this a valid counter example?

Comment: It is indeed a counterexample.

Comment: Yes it is! You can take also $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb {R-Q}$

Comment: ...or $\{0,1\}$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: this is false even if you replace sup and inf with max and min, take $[1,4]$ and $[1,2]\cup[3,4]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid counterexample.